# Is there any better approach to set a Listener n times inside Coroutines?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, kotlin, coroutine

In my project, I am making calls to Firebase Database **n** times inside for loop  based on the size of List and return the result by obtaining the response of each listener. I am doing all this inside **Coroutine**. Here is my code

```
 fun Flow<List<Basket>>.mapBasketListToItemsList() : Flow<List<Items>> = map{it : List<Basket> ->
     val itemsList = Collections.synchronizedList(ArrayList<Items>())

     coroutineScope{
         it.forEach {it : Basket ->
            launch {
                databaseReference.child("Items").child(it.itemsId!!)
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                       override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                       }

                       override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                           if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                               val item = dataSnapshot.getValue(Items::class.java)
                               itemsList.add(item!!)
                           }
                       }
                   })
           }
       }
   }
    itemsList
}
```

But I feel strange as i don't know whether I'm doing this by right way or not. So i wanna know if there is any better **approach** to do this work.

Comment: Hello Mattwalk, welcome to SO. Have you by any chance taken a look at coroutines and continuations? Here's an issue where Firebase is mentioned, perhaps it will give you a pointer in that direction? (it's still a PITA, btw) https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/48

Answer (score 1):

You can't use such operation delivers an asynchronous stream of values with `suspendCoroutine` like functions lest we get `IllegalStateException` when we try to resume continuation the second time, because Kotlin suspension and continuations are single-shot.

Flow is explicitly designed to represent a cold asynchronous stream of multiple values. You can use [`callbackFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) function to convert a multi-shot callback into a flow:

**Example of usage:**

```
fun flowFrom(api: CallbackBasedApi): Flow<T> = callbackFlow {
    val callback = object : Callback { // implementation of some callback interface
        override fun onNextValue(value: T) {
            // To avoid blocking you can configure channel capacity using
            // either buffer(Channel.CONFLATED) or buffer(Channel.UNLIMITED) to avoid overfill
            try {
                sendBlocking(value)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Handle exception from the channel: failure in flow or premature closing
            }
        }
        override fun onApiError(cause: Throwable) {
            cancel(CancellationException("API Error", cause))
        }
        override fun onCompleted() = channel.close()
    }
    api.register(callback)
    /*
     * Suspends until either 'onCompleted'/'onApiError' from the callback is invoked
     * or flow collector is cancelled (e.g. by 'take(1)' or because a collector's coroutine was cancelled).
     * In both cases, callback will be properly unregistered.
     */
        awaitClose { api.unregister(callback) }
    }
```

[Read More](https://medium.com/@elizarov/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf)

Comment: Okay and I have to make a call to this method inside my for loop ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QkMloe5rIUE8xRHtNXWoqRZ0M650P13A/view . Checkout this link, Am i doing right way now ?